# Creating dictionary from a tuple with a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, typeerror

I have the following Tuple `tup` and would like to convert it to a dictionary.
I found code that seems to work. But when I try my own for loop I get an error.
Can someone explain to me why is `dict(y,x)` allowed in the first print but the other one gives an exception?

```
tup = ((2,'x'),(3,'a'))

#CORRECT CODE
print(dict((y, x) for x, y in tup))                 #output: {'x':2, 'a':3}

#my own for loop, that throws the type error
for x, y in tup:
    print(dict(y,x))                                #output: TypeError dict expected at most 
                                                    #        1 argument, got 2
```

Where is the difference between these two loops?

Comment: The first one is not `dict(y, x)`, it is `dict((y, x) for x, y in tup)`.

Comment: Closest you can get is `print(dict([(y,x)]))`

Comment: first off, you cannot expect to "convert" anything to anything else by repeatedly `print`ing. You should make sure you understand the difference between showing something on your screen, and actually doing a calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is equivalent to:

```py
output = {}
tup = ((2,'x'),(3,'a'))

for x, y in tup:
    output[y] = x
```

Which is also equivalent to:

```py
tup = ((2,'x'),(3,'a'))
output = {y:x for (x,y) in tup}
```

It adds a key, value pair for each element of the tuple to the new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

(just for knowledge) another method you can use

```
my_dict={}
for a, b in tup: 
    my_dict.setdefault(a,b)
```

Here we have used the dictionary method setdefault() to convert the first parameter to key and the second to the value of the dictionary